# How to have a div size adjusted to an image displayed size

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with an image inside.
The div has a fixed height, lower than the image intrinsic height.
I want the div's width to be always equal to the "displayed" width of the image (which is a function of the unknown div's height and image's height/width ratio).

[Here is a codepen example of what I want to do (having "shrink" and "other" divs the same width than their child image)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pELBkL)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="shrink">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0f0/fff" />
  </div>
  <div class="other">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/00f/fff" />
  </div>
</div>

div { margin: 5px; }
img { max-height: 100%;  }
.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shrink {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: #88FF88;
}
.other {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: #8888FF;
}
```

Is it possible with only HTML/CSS ie without Javascript ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like this ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLAZjJ

Answer (score 0):

Remove width as an attribute of your container and the div will conform to the width of its contents.

Does this work for you?

Comment: I don't want the "container" div to conform to the width of its content. I want this behaviour for the "shrink" and "other" divs.